# How can I write a opposite regex to this regex?

Tags: regex

this is a regex of a proxy, if I add this to my proxy:

```
(.*\.|)(abc|google)\.(org|net)
```

my proxy will not transmit the `abc.org`, `abc.net`, `google.org`, `google.net`'s traffic.

how can I write a regex opposite to this regex? I mean only transmit the `abc.org`, `abc.net`, `google.org`, `google.net`'s traffic.

---

**EDIT-01**

My thought is just want to transmit `abc.org` or `www.abc.org`, how can I do with that?

Comment: are you sure the double `|` is correct ? [regex101](https://regex101.com/) marks it as a pattern error, if you remove that I properly matches `abc.org`, `abc.net`, `google.org`, `google.net` then you just to edit your code to allow traffic from those sites

Comment: Does your regex flavor support lookaround assertions?  If not, then it might be difficult to do what you are asking here.

Comment: Normally I would suggest you just use `^(?!((.*\.|)(abc|google)\.(org|net)))` but since you have a `.*` inside your base regex you cannot do this. Can you provide some examples of the types of patterns you are trying to match ?

Comment: This regex also matches all the subdomains of the above domains too. so news.abc.org will also provide a match. Other than that I think casualcoder has the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?!(www\.)?(?:abc|google)\.(?:net|org)).*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/WOnFx8/3/

I used `?!` to reverse the matching of your regex. This way, it will match any domain except these specific 4 domains.

Another way to do it is by using this code to include anything before the desired domains:

```
^(?!(.*\.|)(?:abc|google)\.(?:net|org)).*
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/WOnFx8/4/

Comment: seems the abc.net, www.abc.net and other all can not transmit now.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex you write

> (.*\.|)(abc|google)\.(org|net)

mean any string is one of abc.org, gooogle.org, abc.net, google.net, with optional prefix string ends with dot (.)
Like: test.google.org, sub.abc.net,...

I think you want to match string like test.yahoo.com, but not test.google.org. If you can use negative look ahead, this is the answer:

> **^**(.*\.|)**(?!**(abc|google)\.(org|net)**)\w+\.\w+$**

Explain:

- **^** and **$** to be sure your match is entire url string
- Negative look ahead is to check the url is not something like abc.org, abc.net, google.org, google.net
- And **\w+\.\w+** to check the remain string is kind of URL type (something likes yahoo.com, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Im going to assume you have lookaheads, if so then you can simply use -

```
(^.*?\.(?!(abc|google))\w+\.(?:org|net)$)
```

Demo - https://regex101.com/r/5eC41R/3

What this does is -

1. Looks for the start of the url (till the first `.`)
2. Checks that next part is not `abc` or `google`
3. looks for the next section (till the next `.`)
4. Looks for a closing `org` or `net`

Note that since it is a lookahead it will be slow compared to other regex matches

Comment: @244boy hmm, does the demo match your requirements ? if so it may be an issue with how your implementing the regex